# Http call is called only one time, then it's not being called anymore

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm working on Angular 14 app and I have 3 separated forms in the same component, every form has a field named "rut". So when user types some data on rut field on any of this 3 forms, I have to perfom http call to one service to bring data back.

```
listenForRutChanges() {
    const opRutControl = this.operationsFormGroup.get('rut')!;
    const legalRutControl = this.legalFormGroup.get('rut')!;
    const invoiceRutControl = this.invoiceFormGroup.get('rut')!;

    opRutControl?.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(300),
        filter(() => opRutControl.valid),
      )
      .subscribe((value) => {
        this.rutSubject.next({ value, formGroup: this.operationsFormGroup });
      });

    legalRutControl?.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(300),
        filter(() => legalRutControl.valid),
      )
      .subscribe((value) => {
        this.rutSubject.next({ value, formGroup: this.legalFormGroup });
      });

    invoiceRutControl?.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(300),
        filter(() => invoiceRutControl.valid),
      )
      .subscribe((value) => {
        this.rutSubject.next({ value, formGroup: this.invoiceFormGroup });
      });
  }
```

So as you see, I grab the form field for this 3 distinct forms, on valuechanges I wait a time and then I have a behaviourSubject. BehaviourSubject implementation is this:

```
rutSearch() {
    this.searchSubs = this.rutSubject
      .pipe(
        filter(({ value }) => value !== ''),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(({ value, formGroup }) =>
          this.clientService.getDetailsByRut(value).pipe(
            map((clientResponse) => ({ clientResponse, formGroup })),
            catchError(() => of()),
          ),
        ),
      )
      .subscribe(({ clientResponse, formGroup }) => {
        const { clientInfo } = clientResponse.data[0];

        const { email, fullName: name, phoneNumber: phone } = clientInfo;

        formGroup!.patchValue({ name, email, phone }, { emitEvent: false });
      });
  }
```

The problem is that the service is called once. Then even though I detect that other form field has distinct info, the service is not called anymore. Any ideas? Also if you see something that could be refactored please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

I tried instead of making a behavior subject, to call a normal function with http call. But didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the `switchMap` and maybe the `distinctUntilChanged` in `rutSearch`.

The `switchMap` cancels the inner observable if the outer observable emits.

Try the following:

```
filter(({ value }) => value !== ''),
        // distinctUntilChanged(), Remove distinctUntilChanged
        mergeMap(({ value, formGroup }) // switch switchMap to mergeMap
```

I think the main culprit is the `distinctUntilChanged` because it will ignore emissions that are the exact same.

Here is a good article on the differences between `switchMap`, `mergeMap` and `concatMap`.

https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/

In short, `switchMap` cancels the inner observable if an outer observable emits.

`mergeMap` does not do this cancellation behavior.

`concatMap` does not do this cancellation behavior and the inner observable is processed in the same order as the outer observable.